# Exporting a plot inside Manipulate - Update first, then Export

Tags: manipulate, export

I want Mathematica to excute the first action inside the `Button` fully before executing the second action. In particular, look at the following plot which I want to `Export` to a pdf.

```
Manipulate[myFigure=Show[Plot[x^2+a,{x,-1,1},PlotRange->{-1,4}]],{{a,2,"a"},-1,3},Button["Export a=0",{a=0,Export["Figure1.pdf",myFigure];}],Button["Export a=1",{a=1,Export["Figure2.pdf",myFigure];}]]
```

If I click `Export`, Mathematica seems to `Export` the plot before `Updating` the `Manipulate` to the new value for 'a'. However, I obviously want it to change to the new 'a' first, showing the new plot, and then `Export` this plot to a pdf.

Any thoughts on how to make `Manipulate` `Dynamically Update` itself before the `Export`? Or other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (at least for me):

```
Manipulate[
 myFigure = Dynamic@Plot[x^2 + a, {x, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 4}],
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic@a, {-1, 3, 1}],
   Button["Export a=0", {a = 0; Export["Figure1.pdf", myFigure]}],
   Button["Export a=1", {a = 1; Export["Figure2.pdf", myFigure]}]
   }]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks, works for me too. Kinda weird, as the whole point of having an expression inside a Manipulate is that the 'Dynamic@' is implied... But ok, it works.

Comment: Actually, is there a way of Exporting the plot without having to name it? I think the order of the sequence is 1. change 'a', 2. Export, 3. give plot name. The 'Dynamic@' you proposed simply changes the order, with the naming as a 2nd step. By skipping the naming, and exporting the plot directly, the problem could also be solved. As in: Manipulate[Show[Plot[x^2+a,{x,-1,1},PlotRange->{-1,4}]],{{a,2,"a"},-1,3},Button["Export a=0",{a=0,Export["Figure1.pdf",this.Manipulate];}],Button["Export a=1",{a=1,Export["Figure2.pdf",this.Manipulate];}]]

Comment: this.Manipulate doesn't exist in Mathemarica.

Comment: Yeah, obviously :P I was asking if a similar functionality exists.

Comment: @LBogaardt - a similar functionality doesn't exist.